# Распарсить таблицу excel через C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, excel, npoi

У меня есть файл, из которого необходимо заполнить базу данных. Структура файла сложная(например, значение ячейки С6 зависит от Company name1, Type1, Section1). Как его распарсить чтобы заполнить бд данными? 
Для работы с excel я использую npoi. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

получаем лист и файл и передаем функции по обработке эксель

```
private void SelectTableFromExcel(int year)
    {
        var openFile = OpenFile();
        var excelWorksheets = GetExcelWorksheet(openFile);
        TableFromExcel(excelWorksheets, "номер последней колонки");

    }
```

выбираем и открываем файл

```
private OpenFileDialog OpenFile()
    {
        var openFile = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Title = @"Выберите файл",
            Filter = @"Файлы Excel|*.xls;*.xlsx",
            FilterIndex = 1,
            RestoreDirectory = true
        };

        return openFile.ShowDialog() != true ? null : openFile;
    }
```

получаем первый лист из выбранного файла

```
private ExcelWorksheet GetExcelWorksheet(OpenFileDialog openFile)
    {
        var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(openFile.FileName));
        var excelWorksheets = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        return excelWorksheets;
    }
```

основная функция для работы с эксель

```
private void TableFromExcel(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet, string numberCol)
    {
        var rangeExcel = GetRangeExcel(excelWorksheet);
        var lastColRange = GetLastColumnExcel(excelWorksheet, numberCol);

        var nullsRowFromExcel = GetNullRowFromExcel(excelWorksheet, rangeExcel);

        LoadDataFromExcel(excelWorksheet, rangeExcel, nullsRowFromExcel, lastColRange);
    }
```

получаем ячейку, откуда начинают идти данные

```
private ExcelCellAddress GetRangeExcel(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheets)
    {
        return excelWorksheets.Cells[1, 1, excelWorksheets.Dimension.Rows, excelWorksheets.Dimension.Columns]
            .First(c => c.Value != null && c.Value?.ToString().Length != 0 && c.Value.ToString().Contains("Company name1"))
            ?.Start;
    }
```

получаем ячейку по последнему столбцу

```
private ExcelCellAddress GetLastColumnExcel(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet, string numberColumn)
    {
        return excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1, excelWorksheet.Dimension.Rows, excelWorksheet.Dimension.Columns]
            .First(c => c.Value != null && c.Value?.ToString().Length != 0 && c.Value.ToString().Contains(numberColumn))
            ?.Start;
    }
```

получаем нулевые строки, чтобы дальше их пропускать

```
private List<int> GetNullRowFromExcel(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet, ExcelCellAddress rangeExcel)
    {
        var nullRowFromExcel = new List<int>();

        for (var i = rangeExcel.Row; i <= excelWorksheet.Dimension.Rows; i++)
            if (excelWorksheet.Cells[i, rangeExcel.Column - 1].Value == null)
                nullRowFromExcel.Add(i);

        return nullRowFromExcel;
    }
```

считываем данные из эксель

```
private void LoadDataFromExcel(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet, ExcelCellAddress rangeExcel, List<int> nullsRowFromExcel, ExcelCellAddress lastColRange)
    {
        var rowWithAllCollumn = new List<string>();

        for (var i = rangeExcel.Row; i <= excelWorksheet.Dimension.Rows; i++)
        {
            rowWithAllCollumn.Clear();
            for (var j = rangeExcel.Column - 2; j <= lastColRange.Column; j++)
            {
                if (j == rangeExcel.Column - 1 || j > rangeExcel.Column)
                {
                    rowWithAllCollumn.Add(excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value == null ? "0" : excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    rowWithAllCollumn.Add(null);
                }
            }
            if (nullsRowFromExcel.Contains(i)) continue;
             //_plansEntities это dataContext в entity framework, LoadPlanMZTemps моя таблица,куда надо грузить данные
            _plansEntities.LoadPlanMZTemps.Add(ChangesListToModel(rowWithAllCollumn, lastColRange.Column));
            _plansEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

тут уже вставляем в таблицу данные

```
private LoadPlanMZTemp ChangesListToModel(List<string> rowWithAllCollumn, int lastColumn)
    {
//моя модель из ef
        var objPlan = new LoadPlanMZTemp();
        var descr = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(objPlan);
        var index = 0;

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in descr)
        {
            if (index < lastColumn)
            {
                switch (property.Name)
                {
                    case "id":
                        continue;
                    default:
                        property.SetValue(objPlan, System.Convert.ToDecimal(rowWithAllCollumn[index]));
                        break;
                }
                index++;
            }
            else break;
        }

        return objPlan;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я для работы с `Excel` использую `EpPlus`, но я уверен, что принцип работы один и тот же.

Как я понимаю, формат вам заранее известен => идете как по двумерному массиву и постепенно заполняете `DataTable`:

1. Прочитали заголовок и создали соответствующее кол-во колонок с названиями
2. Далее итеративно спускаетесь вниз и генерите DataRow'ы
3. В конце просто пуляете этот DataTable в БД и все.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, необходимо этот файл разбить на несколько таблиц(справочников) и заполнять ими бд?

Comment: Ну если этот Excel нужно в разные таблицы засунуть, то да.

Comment: Нет. Нужно из этого экселя данные в базу данных записать.

Comment: @КириллБалашов Что вы подразумеваете  под базой данных? В БД может быть, как 1 таблицы, так и несколько. Если этот Excek нужно записать в БД, но данные растаклать по разным таблицам, то файл нужно бить на несколько таблиц.

Comment: Основная задача - создать бд и заполнить ее данными. Данные берутся из файлов, шаблон которого я показал. Я создал несколько сущностей в БД исходя из заголовков вот этой большой таблицы.

Comment: База данных MS SQL

Comment: @КириллБалашов Ну, заполняйте ее как вам нужно. Я лишь описал общий алгоритм работы с Excel'ем - это работа как с двумерным массивом.

Comment: Да это понятно. Меня напрягает, что для каждого значения надо смотреть Section, Company name и Subtype одновременно...